# Adjusting vertically line with vertically text in android

Tags: android, android-layout

Below is a picture I want to design in android.

Here is my whole activity_main.xml code.

http://pastebin.com/GWP9cnHA

Here is my code specific layout.

```
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:background="@color/views_bg_color"
            android:orientation="vertical"

            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp">

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:background="#FF0000FF" />

            <com.example.alphabook.helper.VerticalTextView
                style="@style/verticalTextStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="bottom|right"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="@string/views_text"

                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@color/views_text_color"
                android:textSize="53dp" />



        </LinearLayout>
```

Here is my colors.xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!--Colors for MainActivity Start-->
    <color name="intel_bg_color">#00ACB8</color>
    <color name="macro_bg_color">#72B669</color>
    <color name="views_bg_color">#E8AF58</color>
    <color name="risks_bg_color">#FE5B3C</color>
    <color name="g20_bg_color">#7268A5</color>
    <color name="markets_bg_color">#66A8CB</color>

    <color name="intel_line_color">#3FC0C9</color>
    <color name="intel_border_line_color">#00676E</color>
    <color name="macro_line_color">#95C88E</color>
    <color name="macro_border_line_color">#446D3F</color>

    <color name="intel_text_color">#E5F7F8</color>
    <color name="macro_text_color">#F0F8F0</color>
    <color name="views_text_color">#FDF7ED</color>
    <!--Colors for MainActivity End-->
</resources>
```

I am not enable to adjust the vertical line with vertical text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below code if there is still problem then i will need VerticalTextView class and supporting styles you are using to make it perfect.

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:background="@color/views_bg_color"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp">

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FF0000FF" />

    <com.example.alphabook.helper.VerticalTextView
        style="@style/verticalTextStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="@string/views_text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@color/views_text_color"
        android:textSize="53dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The problem is in my orientation of LinearLayout?

Comment: Yes. You were using vertical orientation

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a view, you can create a `drawable` for vertical and another for horizontal line. For example, vertical line drawable `vertical_line.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="rectangle" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#fff"/>
    <size android:height="35dp" android:width="2dp"/>
</shape>
```

Then in your `TextView` simply use it in your `drawableRight` like this

```
<com.example.alphabook.helper.VerticalTextView
                .
                . 
                .
 android:drawableRight="@drawable/vertical_line"
 android:drawableEnd="@drawable/vertical_line" />
```

Comment: This will spare you and Android from adding the probably unnecessary `LinearLayout` and `View`